# Holoviews: separate figures with same coloring and scaling

Tags: colors, figure, holoviews

Let's say that I have two `Raster` objects (or any other Holoviews object really). I can easily visualize one with appropriate color scaling, and I can do a layout to get both figures with the same scaling and coloring. What if I want to do two figures (e.g. because I need them on different pages), but with the same coloring and scaling so that the figures are comparable. 
If there's no way to do this automatically, is there any way to access the relevant settings and then feed them manually to the second figure?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a notebook: `The %opts line magic : IPython specific syntax applied globally [string format]`http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html and I think hv.opts works globally in script.

For both backends, you can do `hv.renderer('bokeh').get_plot(your_element_variable).state` (or replace `bokeh` with `matplotlib`) and get the original bokeh/matplotlib items.

Then you can use matplotlib's `plt.getp()` or bokeh's attribute calling (as I've done here https://github.com/ahuang11/holoext/blob/master/holoext/xbokeh.py#L501-L508) to get the base item's color/font/labels/etc.